# How do I get past this certificate error when I connect to SQL Server from Python / Debian Bullseye?

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc

I've recently been trying to upgrade a Dockerized project that used SQL Server Driver 17 to v18, I've noticed this error every time my program tries to connect to SQL Server:

```
    def connect(self, *cargs, **cparams):
        # inherits the docstring from interfaces.Dialect.connect
>       return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
E       sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:self signed certificate] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')
E       (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Is there some additional component I need to install to give my Docker container the necessary certificate? I'm not aware that we even had to use certificates to connect to the SQL Server before - this seems to be a new requirement with the v18 driver.